# Quotation Mark Order

Tags: javascript, onclick, queryselector

I have the following element:

<a onclick="document.querySelector('[action*="12345"] .cbSearchButton').click()" >

And I seem to be having an issue once I added that wildcard selector because it seemed to be interfering with the quotes - i think the opening double quote in the 12345 is being interpreted as the closing double quote for the document.querySelector. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quotes and escape them, here is how:

```
<a onclick="document.querySelector('[action*=\'12345\'] .cbSearchButton').click()" >
```